# Which cts: query to use to eliminate the doc that contains a particular element?

Tags: marklogic

I'm pulling a list of uris from **meters** database based on a **timestamp**. This is the code -

```
cts:uris( (),  (),  cts:and-query((
                cts:collection-query("meters") ,
                cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("mt:period"), "raw"),
                cts:element-range-query( xs:QName("mt:end-time"),  ">=", xs:dateTime("2018-02-17T05:37:00") ),
)
                 )
                              ))
```

But it is including **keystore-raw.xml** which is not the file that i want in the result set? How can I remove it from the result set. The parent element is `keystore-metrics` and also has elements like `keystore-metric`. I don't want any for loop.

Answer (score 5):

To make sure an element exists in a document:

```
cts:element-query(xs:QName("Your-element"), cts:true-query())
```

To make sure an element does NOT exist in a document:

```
cts:not-query(cts:element-query(xs:QName("Your-element"), cts:true-query()))
```

Why does this work?  Because the [cts:element-query()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-query) confirms that the element is in the document and the [cts:true-query()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:true-query) satisfies the requirements of the cts:element-query()

Comment: I tried this excluding the cts:true-query part. It didn't worked. It still returned that xml that was unwanted.